# What is some prerequisite of global differential geometry other than real analysis and advanced calculus?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, soft-question

What are some prerequisites for global differential geometry other than real analysis and advanced calculus?

It introduces a lot of new definitions other than the ones from the local differential geometry, say two or three dimensional differential geometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all,it really matters here what you mean by those 2 terms,because they mean somewhat different things at different universities. I assume by advanced calculus,you mean either a careful treatment of single variable calculus or a careful treatment of vector analysis/multivariable calculus and by real analysis,you mean a treatment of calculus on abstract metric spaces a la "baby" Rudin or Pugh. You definitely need **at least** a careful treatment of calculus on the real line first along with a serious linear algebra course, one that proves everything. In many ways, modern differential geometry is the study of vector spaces that happen to be topological spaces-the vector space structure is what allows us to build differential calculus on these spaces i.e. tangent spaces and bundles.

The other thing you'll need some background in is basic topology-topological spaces,open and closed sets, continuity, compactness, and connectedness-and that's really where a metric-spaces based analysis background would make things much easier since most the basic concepts are covered in the special case of metric spaces.A geometrically-flavored first course in topology that covers the fundamental group and defines homotopies-such as one based on *A First Course in Topology* by John McCleary or *Introduction to Topological Manifolds* by John M.Lee would be even better,but isn't necessary. The topology background is really essential for understanding differentiable manifolds and while you can get by with just real analysis on metric spaces, expect the course to be **much** more demanding then if you'd had at least a basic topology course. If I was advising you, I'd tell you to postpone a serious differentiable manifolds course until you've had a decent first course in topology.